# ValueError: got_ver is None when importing Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When I try to import Tensorflow `2.6.0` on a `conda` virtual environment with `python 3.9.5` on my M1 mac, I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/gulag_dweller/Desktop/Lab_stuff/Bert/train_bert.py", line 1, in <module>
   import transformers as tf
 File "/Users/gulag_dweller/mambaforge/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
   from . import dependency_versions_check
 File "/Users/gulag_dweller/mambaforge/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/dependency_versions_check.py", line 41, in <module>
   require_version_core(deps[pkg])
 File "/Users/gulag_dweller/mambaforge/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/versions.py", line 120, in require_version_core
   return require_version(requirement, hint)
 File "/Users/gulag_dweller/mambaforge/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/versions.py", line 114, in require_version
   _compare_versions(op, got_ver, want_ver, requirement, pkg, hint)
 File "/Users/gulag_dweller/mambaforge/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/versions.py", line 45, in _compare_versions
   raise ValueError("got_ver is None")
ValueError: got_ver is None
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Reinstalling Transformers will fix this issue. `pip uninstall transformers` and then `pip install transformers`. Make sure numpy is installed and is placed in same directory where Transformer is installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting this error, it's because some package that transformers is dependent on is not getting the version it expects. Transformers checks the versions of all its dependencies.

For me on macOS, I had multiple numpy packages in `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages`. To fix the issue, I deleted all numpy references in /site-packages and reinstalled numpy: `pip install numpy`.

To really discover what's going on, you can print out the pkg that's failing the version check and then re-run your import in python:

[image]

Then debug why that package is failing the version check in the first place.

I noticed I was getting "None" doing this:

```
from importlib_metadata import version
print(version('numpy'))
```